# How to force text in an HTML table to start at a certain distance from the top of the cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

Right now, I have the side, and top and bottom padding set, but while that is the same for each cell, when there is more text in the one cell, the height at which the text starts is different based on how much text there is. What should I be doing so that the text starts at the same distance from the top of the cell regardless of the amount of text, and then pushes down from there? So that I end up with something like this:

[image: http://cl . ly/WoRh]

as opposed to something like this:

[image: http://cl . ly/Wol0]

Current code:

```
.bottom-table td {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Also have some code that styles the table as a whole (don't think it would be relevant, but here it is):

```
.bottom-table {
    -moz-border-radius: 15px !important;
    border-radius: 15px !important;
    border: 2px solid black !important;
    width: 75%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle with the relevant code: http://jsfiddle.net/zLyNm/

Comment: Use `vertical-align:top;` in your `td`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to `.bottom-table td`.

```
.bottom-table td {
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8T57/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use *witdth* property or can use *margin* or you can use *colspan* and *rowspan* property..

Comment: Ok... Any more info on that?